# How to check Global HTTP batch endpoint is called

Tags: google-api

I received an email saying that JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch serving endpoints being discontinued, and that my project on Google Cloud Platform is calling Global HTTP Batch endpoint.

When I check the API dashboard of the project, however, "[Google Cloud Storage JSON API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/storage-api.googleapis.com/overview)" shows no usage for the last 30 days.

Does that mean the project no longer calls this endpoint?
If not (= if there is still a chance that we call this endpoint), how can I see whether a change that I will make to eliminate the call does actually eliminate the call?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a client from Google to make your request you are no longer calling the Global HTTP Batch endpoint as they have been updated to use the new API specific Batch endpoint.

You can still use the dev tools from your browser to check the request url from your app.